# i am using multiple nestjs servers and i am using nginx as a api-gateway from the front to the the specific backend server but its not working

Tags: nginx, nestjs, api-gateway

i want to build a docker image that contains a nginx server for routing the requests of the front to the specific nestjs microservice

```
events {

}
http {

    upstream user_management {
        server localhost:3001;
    }
    
    upstream product_management {
        server localhost:3000;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        location /users {
            proxy_pass http://user_management/api/v1/users;
        }

        location /api/v1/ {
            proxy_pass http://product_management/api/v1/products;
        }

        location /test {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index index.html;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/Products;
            # root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            # index index.html;
        }
    }
}
```

```
FROM nginx:latest
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

i want route requests of the front app to the specific microservice via an nginx api-gateway but it does not work using docker

Answer (score 0):

Localhost is referring to nginx container, nothing else.

Your shown Dockerfile is only running nginx, not NestJS